# Duplicate form fields for has many leads to blank parameters and errors

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, http, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I have the following inputs in active-admin

```
f.inputs 'Programme description' do
  f.input :nationalities, 
    as: :select, 
    hint: 'Nationalität des Suchenden', 
    collection: all_countries,
    input_html: {multiple: true, class: 'select2', style: 'width: 70%'}
end
```

Please note that there are three form fields with the name `programme[nationality_ids][]`.

```
<li class="select input optional" id="programme_nationalities_input">

<input name="programme[nationality_ids][]" type="hidden" value="" />

<label class="label" for="programme_nationality_ids">Nationalities</label>

<input name="programme[nationality_ids][]" type="hidden" value="" />

<select class="select2" 
  id="programme_nationality_ids" 
  multiple="multiple" 
  name="programme[nationality_ids][]" 
  placeholder="Type country name" 
  style="width: 70%">

<option value="CH">Switzerland</option>
<option value="LI">Liechtenstein</option>
<option value="DE">Germany</option>
<option value="AT">Austria</option>
<option value="FR">France</option>
<option value="IT">Italy</option>

</select>
```

These inserted hidden form fields, lead to empty parameters, which in turn lead to an exception, because the empty string is converted to a `0` and no object with the `id=0` can be found.

How can I clean up these parameters and hence avoid the exception.

```
"nationality_ids"=>["", "", "FR"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ActiveAdmin model that contains the form:

```
controller do
  def create
    params[:programme][:nationality_ids].reject! {|nat_id| nat_id.blank?}
    create!
  end

  def update
    params[:programme][:nationality_ids].reject! {|nat_id| nat_id.blank?}
    update!
  end
end
```